# Как удалить повторяющиеся даты в String?

Tags: java

имеется строка вида:

```
№;Задача;T;O;P
;2016-01-18
1. ;task1;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-18
2. ;task2;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-18
3. ;task3;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-19
7. ;33333;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-19
8. ;d;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-19
9. ;00;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-20
21. ;task1;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-20
22. ;task2;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-21
25. ;testtime;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-21
26. ;fgghgfh;23:45;.;, new t.
```

как удалить из нее повторяющиеся даты и оставить только одну самую первую, чтоб в конечном итоге получилось такой вид

```
№;Задача;T;O;P
;2016-01-18
1. ;task1;03:00;.; 
2. ;task2;03:00;.; 
3. ;task3;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-19
7. ;33333;03:00;.; 
8. ;d;03:00;.; 
9. ;00;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-20
21. ;task1;03:00;.; 
22. ;task2;03:00;.; 
;2016-01-21
25. ;testtime;03:00;.; 
26. ;fgghgfh;23:45;.;, new t.
```

ваш второй ответ подошел для верхнего примера, подскажите пожалуйста для данного примера как сделать тоже самое чтоб удалил даты одинаковые

```
   <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-18</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>1.  </td><td>task1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><th></th><th>2016-01-18</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>2. </td><td>task2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-18</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>6. </td><td>task4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:33</td><td>.</td><td>, text</td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-19</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>18. </td><td>trtt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:08</td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-19</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>19. </td><td>klkkl&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:44</td><td>.</td><td>, new t.</td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-19</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>20. </td><td>hhh 565&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:59</td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
 <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-20</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>21. </td><td>task1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
 <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-20</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>22. </td><td>task2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-20</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>23. </td><td>task3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td>, extra t.</td></tr>
 <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-21</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>25. </td><td>testtime&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-21</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>26.  </td><td>sdas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td>, qqwweerrtt</td></tr>
  <tr><th></th><th>2016-01-21</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>27.  </td><td>in 3:00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td> <td>, 12345</td></tr>
```

привести к виду

```
<tr><th></th><th>2016-01-18</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>1. </td><td>task1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>2. </td><td>task2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>6. </td><td>task4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:33</td><td>.</td><td>, text</td></tr>
<tr><td>18. </td><td>trtt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:08</td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><th></th><th>2016-01-19</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>19. </td><td>klkkl&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:44</td><td>.</td><td>, new t.</td></tr>
<tr><td>20. </td><td>hhh 565&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>23:59</td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><th></th><th>2016-01-20</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>21. </td><td>task1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>22. </td><td>task2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>23. </td><td>task3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td>, extra t.</td></tr>
<tr><td>25. </td><td>testtime&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><th></th><th>2016-01-21</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>26. </td><td>sdas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td>, qqwweerrtt</td></tr>
<tr><td>27. </td><td>in 3:00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td></td><td>.</td><td>, 12345</td></tr>
```

если не сложно объясните как работает ваш код, не совсем понял его но он отлично подошел к первому моему примеру, как я понял проблема в первой строке если я ее меняю то выходит ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение вытекает из бага в [связанном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484936/patternsyntaxexception?lq=1). Из-за бага в Java старых версий необходимо избавиться от ретроспективной позиционной проверки, потому что регулярное выражение

```
(?<=(;\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\n).{0,30})\1
```

вызывает ошибку.

Регулярное выражение решающее поставленную задачу:

```
/(?<=(;\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\n))((?:[^;]++|;)*?)\1/g
```

В нем во избежание проявления бага используется ретроспективная позиционная проверка постоянной длины.
[Живой пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pN1vV7/1)

Оно подвержено легкой оптимизации по привычке, его более простая форма:

```
(?<=(;\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\n))(.*?)\1/gs
```

Тоже самое, но в Java:

```
String regex = "(?<=(;\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\n))((?:[^;]++|;)*?)\\1";
text = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( text ).replaceAll( "$2" );
```

[Живой пример на IDEone](http://ideone.com/q8Xb4Z)