# PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения, android-studio, netbeans

Функция возвращает строку данного вида, и с помощью регулярного выражения я ее привожу к нужному виду, в NetBeans код работает без проблем, но в Android Studio такая ошибка, в чем может быть проблема?

```
String s = "№;Задача;T;O;P\n"
+ ";2016-01-18\n"
+ "1. ;task1;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-18\n"
+ "2. ;task2;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-18\n"
+ "3. ;task3;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-19\n"
+ "7. ;33333;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-19\n"
+ "8. ;d;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-19\n"
+ "9. ;00;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-20\n"
+ "21. ;task1;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-20\n"
+ "22. ;task2;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-21\n"
+ "25. ;testtime;03:00;.; \n"
+ ";2016-01-21\n"
+ "26. ;fgghgfh;23:45;.;, new t.\n";

String regex = "(?<=(;\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\n).{0,30})\\1";
String result = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(s).replaceAll("");

System.out.println( result );
```

вот ошибка

```
01-22 00:51:10.072 12001-12001/com.jaloveast1k.topbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.jaloveast1k.topbook, PID: 12001
                                                                     java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 9:
                                                                     (?<=(;\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d
                                                                     ).{0,30})\1
                                                                              ^
                                                                         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
                                                                         at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
                                                                         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
                                                                         at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity.sendTasks(MainActivity.java:1669)
                                                                         at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity.send(MainActivity.java:1600)
                                                                         at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity.access$700(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                         at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity$9.onClick(MainActivity.java:224)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

если меняю интервал с {0,30} на {0,9}, то ошибка пропадает, но тогда не срабатывает регулярное выражение

Comment: чет не понял, какая ошибка?

Comment: исправил вопрос)

Comment: @java, судя по гуглу вы что-то не экранировали...Похоже, что это `\n`

Comment: а почему данный код с интервалом {0,30} работает без проблем в NetBeans

Comment: я за экранировал `\n`, но ничего не изменилось, тока index ошибки сменился с index 9 на index 34

Comment: Почему же не изменилось? Ошибка стала другой, а значит `\n` таки надо было экранировать... Просто теперь ещё другая ошибка в другом месте вылезла. Видать, надо как-то и `1` прекранировать. Или что-там у вас под 34-ым индексом...

Comment: я просто не понимаю, если в  коде ошибка, то почему данный код в NetBeans работает?

Comment: а как `1`  прекранировать

Comment: Ну, видимо по разному там всё это устроено... Конретно ничего не скажу - я в регулярках ничего не понимаю... Может с утра кто набежит сюда из разбирающихся)

Comment: Может единичку надо фигурными окружить?..

Comment: понял, спасибо, буду надеяться)

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Кстати, вам уведомления приходят, т.к. я комменты под вашим вопросом пишу. А мне о ваших комментах не приходят, т.к. вы меня чрез `@` не поминаете)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо я не знал об этом) и скобки не помогли

Comment: Регулярное выражение полностью корректно с точки зрения PCRE, у меня оно работает без ошибок. Если не дадут ответ по источнику проблемы, то поковыряю несколько позже, пока могу предложить полностью равнозначный вариант по совпавшему результату: `(;\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\n)(?=.{0,30}\\1)` Если регулярное выражение нужно для replace или split, то оно не равнозначно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему так:

Это баг в ICU ([#40103](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40103) в AOSP, [#10024](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/10024]) в ICU trac, [изменения](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/changeset/33835)), поправлен в ICU 52, до андроида исправление добралось только вместе с ICU 53 в API 21 (Lollipop).

Баг не позволяет использовать квантификаторы с большой верхней границей внутри look-behind (конструкция `.{0,10}` у меня на эмуляторе проблем не вызывает, но я слишком слабо понимаю код ICU, чтобы объяснить, почему).

Что делать:

- [Переписать регулярное выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485581/190934).
- Не использовать регулярное выражение.
- Заменить `.{0,30}` на три `.{0,10}` (с потерей производительности, видимо)
- Сделать пирамидку из `(.|..|...|....)` и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему по другому вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484876) объяснение

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer( s, "\n" );
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder( s.length()*2/3 );

String prevDate = "";
newString.append( tok.nextToken() ).append( '\n' ); // заголовок
while( tok.hasMoreTokens() ) {
String date = tok.nextToken();                  // дата
if ( !prevDate.equals( date ) ) {
    prevDate = date;
    newString.append( prevDate ).append( '\n' );
}
newString.append( tok.nextToken() ).append( '\n' ); // данные
}

System.out.println( newString.toString() );
```

Comment: Не вижу там никакого объяснения такого поведения Java. Вижу только баян про "Теперь у Вас две проблемы". Хотя нет ничего проще регексов.

Comment: ну не знаю, вторым способом то что там был в ответе все заработало, а регулярками ниче не вышло не знаю в чем проблема именно в андроид студио так

Comment: @ReinRaus, если вы можете помочь с регулярками помогите пожалуйста, я добавил новую проблему [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484876)

Comment: Если Вам нужна помощь, то покажите каким способом используется полученный результат.

Comment: @ReinRaus, нет, спасибо, я уже решил проблему, оказалось все было еще легче, без использования регулярок, я немного изменил код в цикле и даты начали выводиться как нужно без всяких манипуляций с конечным String-ом